# Eclipse Mercurial Plugin 2 computer

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I want to use MercurialEclipse to share my files between my mac and my windows computer. I installed the plugin on both and tried to commit+push the files from the mac into a repository of googlecode. Now I am trying to pull the files from the googlecode repository onto my windows computer. But it won't work, there aren't any files in the wizard.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first clone the repository on the target computer, `hg clone`.  Sometimes I just copy the .hg directory (and down) from the source's root to where I want to create the new clone.  In particular I've done this for creating the repository on a central server.